# AngularJS ui-router navigating states with $state.params and queries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app with multiple states that each have nested views.  The one state has a conditional templateUrl, and based on a `$state.param` will show specific HTML/JS. I want to set a query on the URL of the state, so that I know which list item is being looked at when I click it.  I cannot figure out how to set a url query and transition to the desired state's view.

My states:

```
 .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            '@' : {
                templateUrl: 'views/layout.html'
            },
            'top@index' : {
                templateUrl: 'views/top.html',
                controller: function($scope, $state) {
                    $scope.logOut = function() {
                        $state.go('login');
                    };
                }
            },
            'left@index' : { templateUrl: 'views/left.html' },
            'main@index' : { templateUrl: 'views/main.html' }
        }
    })
    .state('index.list', {
        url: 'list?item',
        templateUrl: 'views/lists/list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
    })
    .state('index.list.details', {
        url: '/',
        params: {
            detail: 'overview'
        },
        controller: ctrl,
        views: {
            'details@index' : {
                templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
                    if($stateParams.detail === 'status' ) {
                        ctrl = 'StatusCtrl';
                        return 'views/details/status.html';
                    } else if ($stateParams.detail === 'overview') {
                        ctrl = 'OverviewCtrl';
                        return 'views/details/overview.html';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    })
```

In my controller for the `index.list`, this is where I have the list and click and populate the details view.

HTML & Js:

```
<div class="channel" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="viewListDetails(item)">

$scope.viewListDetails = function(item) {
    $location.search('item', item.id);
    $state.go('index.list.details', {detail: 'status'}, {reload: true})
};
```

My JS above runs the through the function however it does nothing! It will not set the query or transition to the desired view for that sate.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: @koox00 no, no errors at all!!

Comment: put this in the application.run =>   `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));` to log transition errors,  maybe it fails silently.

Answer (score 0):

`index.deviceList.detail` is not a defined state. You probably intended to write `index.list.details`.

Comment: Whoops that's my typo in copy and paste into stack overflow, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You should debug your code and see what `templateUrl` return when you click, or event if the function is even called at all. Also those  `ctrl = 'OverviewCtrl';` looks not right, as `ctrl` is not defined.